# prove that there exists $E$ such that $m(X/E)=0$ and $\lim_k(f_k(x))=0$ for all $x\in E$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, borel-measures

$(X,S,\mu)$ is a measure space ${f_k}$ are S- measurable real- valued functions such that, $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \int|f_k|d\mu<\infty$, prove that there exists $E\in S$ such that $m(X/E)=0$ and $\lim_k(f_k(x))=0$ for all $x\in E$.

My work-

since $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \int|f_k|d\mu<\infty$

$\lim_k(\int |f_k(x)|)=0$

then, by the limit definition, for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists $K$ such that for all $k>K$

$\int |f_k(x)|<\epsilon$. I'm stuck in here.

How do I proceed from here to show that
$\lim_k(|f_k(x)|)=0$

Is there any other approach? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Use the MCT to see

$$\sum \int|f_k|\,d\mu = \int(\sum |f_k|)\,d\mu.$$

Think about what must be true of $\sum |f_k|$ for the last integral to be finite.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It makes sense now. $\sum|f_k|$ should be finite almost every where, and this implies $lim|f_k|$ is zero almost every where as $k$ goes to $\infty$. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

Set $g_n=\sum_{j=1}^n |f_i|$. Then $g_n\le g_{n+1}$ for every $n\in \mathbb N$.

$g:=\lim_{n\to \infty}g_n=\sum_{i=1}^\infty |f_i|$. $g$ is measurable as it is the limit of measurable functions.

By Monotone convergence theorem, $\lim_n\int g_n =\int \sum |f_i|$

In other words, $\sum_i \int |f_i|=\int \sum|f_i|$.

Consider $E:=g^{-1}(\{\infty\}), n\in \mathbb N$.

**Claim**: $\mu(E)=0$

**Pf:**  If not, then $\infty=\int g\chi_{E_n}\le \int g $, contradiction.

So $\mu(E)=0$. Then, $E':= X\setminus E\in S$ works.